# Запятая перед союзом "и" между сказуемыми в императивном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и, сказуемые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: **"Нанесите на кожу и наслаждайтесь приятными ощущениями"**?

И, если можно, то дайте ссылку на правило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, потому что *нанесите* и *наслаждайтесь* — однородные сказуемые. Правило гласит, что запятая не ставится, если однородные члены предложения соединены неповторяющимся сочинительным союзом *и*.

Comment: Меня смущает, что глаголы имеют разный вид, и вторая часть может подходить под условно-уступительную связь: Нанесите, чтобы наслаждаться.

Comment: Вот похожая ситуация (поверните, чтобы выйти). Консультанты не предлагают поставить запятую:  Вопрос № 256133    Здравствуйте, правильно ли написана фраза "Поднявшись по эскалатору, поверните налево и выйдете к магазину"? И если нет, то как грамотно? Ответ справочной службы русского языка 
Здесь верно: **поверните и выйдИте.** (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=256133+)

Comment: Впрочем, не все так просто. Некоторые видят здесь ССП  и предлагают поставить запятую или тире.  Скорее всего, все три решения допустимы.